# How to use the same variable in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up a MySql database containing several tables (needed for uploading tons of data that is entered in excel). I would like to use each table name as a variables that automatically updates each time a new table is added to the database. However, I don't know how to prevent PHP from overwriting my $tableName variable in loops. This is what I got so far:

```
        <?php

            if (!mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
                echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
                exit;
            }

            $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $database";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if (!$result) {
                echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
                echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
                exit;
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                $tableName = $row[0];
                include('../design.php');
            }


        ?>
```

In other words: On the frontpage of the website I would like to include data from every single database table. I have organized a framework for extracting that data and presenting it neatly in design.php. However, this file makes use of the $tableName variable for extracting the data and I think that variable is being overwritten at each loop causing the error (only the number one table will be displayed).

Instead, if I just separate the code in their own php objects, then everything works just fine:

```
        <?php
            $tableName = tablename1;
            include('../design.php');
        ?>
        <?php
            $tableName = tablename2;
            include('../design.php');
        ?>
        etc..
```

Can anyone explain to me how this works? Or if there is some smarter way of doing things?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I would like to use each table name as a variables that automatically updates each time a new table is added to the database."* - Why not just use a trigger?

Comment: This is a pretty bad way to do things (with `include`). Whatever you have in `design.php`, turn it into a function that uses the `tableName` as a parameter and only include the file once at the top. I suspect your `design.php` file uses `$row` or `$result` which would account for your code breaking.

Comment: Try printing out `$tableName` right before each include, and see what happens.

Comment: You should include `design.php` **outside** the `while` loop What's inside `design.php`  ?

Comment: Put db names in array and create function and use it in foreach(for example) instead of including some file also dont use mysql_* function they are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`include` the `design.php` file at the beginning of the script. Inside this file, define a function.

```
function doSomethingWithTableName ($table)
{
    // do something with it
}
```

Then, in your frontend file, you would do this:

```
$sql = "...";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $processed_data = doSomethingWithTableName ($row[0]);
    // do something with $processed_data
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what's inside `design.php` but instead of including it inside the loop I'd create a function, something like:

```
function designFunction($tableName){
//put the design.php here
return $something;
}
```

Now use the `designFunction` inside your loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $tableName = $row[0];
  $someResult = designFunction($tableName);
  //etc...
}
```